# Parse getJson with variable

Tags: javascript, json

I get a Json and i need parse them with a variable...

I get my JSON inside 'data' variable:

```
var artista = data.response.docs[i].band;
var titulo = data.response.docs[i].title;
var id_musica = data.response.docs[i].id;
var trecho = data.highlighting.id_musica.letra[0];
```

My issue is in 'trecho' variable. I need to grab them through the variable 'Id_muisca', but is not a Json key...

It's possible?
[Json Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvZTE.png)
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for indexer notation: `data.highlighting[id_musica].letra`